# PHP - How can i get specific number of characters after last occurence of a character in a string

Tags: php

This is the string `http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-pure-360-mens-golf-shoes-283042?colcode=28304201`

How can i get the first SIX characters after the last occurence of `-` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know how even this can be done..

Comment: You find the last occurrence using the function that exists for this purpose, then get the substring of required length starting from that position using the function that exists for *that* purpose. In both cases Google and "I'm feeling lucky" would be enough; it is difficult to believe you searched but couldn't find them.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways to skin the cat on this one.

[Here's one of them](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dgS):

```
$url = 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-pure-360-mens-golf-shoes-283042?colcode=28304201';
preg_match('/-(\d+)\?/', $url, $result);
var_dump($result[1]); // string(6) "283042"
```

The pattern says "match at least one consecutive number that lies between a dash and a question mark".

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-pure-360-mens-golf-shoes-283042?colcode=28304201";
if(strrpos($link, '-')){  // check if "-" is exist
 echo substr($link,strrpos($link, '-')+1,6);
}
```

strrpos - Finds the position of the last occurrence of a string inside another string

Comment: outputs: `pure-3`. (I suspect the desired output is `283042`)

Comment: sry didnt notice.. i thought you want after the first occurence of '-'.. 
@Robbie Averill put a very good answer

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it get the first six characters after the last occurence of -

Answer (score 0):

try this may help

```
   <?php
$str = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-pure-360-mens-golf-shoes-283042?colcode=28304201";
$at = strtok($str, "?");
if ($at) {
    $sixltr = substr($at, -6);
    echo $sixltr;
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice approach - you need to go the other way though (before the ?)

Comment: oh sorry i thought he want  string after "?"

Comment: You should fix your answer, but make it clear that you have edited it.